# Microsoft Teams demands reinstall

Tags: ms-office

I'm running Catalina 10.15.7 and Microsoft Teams v1.3.00.24758
When I open Teams, I get a popup that blocks the screen, and keeps me from using the app.  It says:

```
We've fixed things so updating the app is easier. Please reinstall Teams.
```

There's a button to download and reinstall Teams.  Downloading and reinstalling Teams fixes the problem until...the computer returns from sleep or restarts.
I've tried deleting the `.plist` files for Teams, but that didn't help.  I've also reset my keychain.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you [reached out to Microsoft Teams support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/home/contact?ContactUsExperienceEntryPointAssetId=S.HP.teams)?

Comment: Is Teams installed in `/Applications` or in some other folder? Which is the version of Teams after reinstalling?